# calling useMutation in a loop like useQueries in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Even I would like to have the same functionality, where i need to call useMutation in Side a loop where data is prepared and send as payload

```
 aDeleteVariantData.forEach((oDeleteItem, nIndex) => {
    oDeleteVariants.mutate(oDeleteItem);
    
    // We are able to delete with axios directly but not using the mutate functionality.
    // how should achive this.
    //     delete(`/varient varientId= ${(oDeleteItem.id)}`)
     //For Each delete we have different url parameters which is not possible with the mutate
    // Is there anything like useQuries for useMutate
```

});

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your mutate function fire off many delete requests via `Promise.all`. It would still be only one mutation then.

Comment: Url parameters of each iteration is different. So axios instance changes for each iteration . so need to create mutation function dynamically. In useQuries it is possible to pass an array of query function So would like to achieve the same functionality for mutation